# Java File Path Windows/Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, sqlite, file

What is the best solution to create file path in Java for this two OS. Application will be used for these OS, thus I need to create universal String.

For example :

For Linux:

```
File folderTxt = new File("/home/romankooo/work/txt/");
```

For Windows:

```
File folderTxt = new File("C:\\PDFMalwareDataAnalyser\\Txt\\");
```

Or is the best solution to generate 2 jar files for this OS.

Comment: Answer depends on the purpose of the folder. Creating temporary files? Providing configuration files? Reading and writing data files? Storing user preferences? Etcetera. For each of those purposes there are well defined cross platform solutions.

Answer (score 37):

The best thing is to let java decide that for you like this

```
File folderTxt = new File(File.separator + "home" + File.separator + "romankooo" + File.separator + "work" + File.separator + "txt" + File.separator);
```

Comment: It is good if the file path is visible somewhere. If user can't see the path then simpler solution is to use slash '/' everywhere.

Answer (score 12):

You can use slash character as file separator for both OS, in other words you can use `C:/PDFMalwareDataAnalyser/Txt/` instead of `C:\\PDFMalwareDataAnalyser\\Txt\\` it will still work on Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line of code and according to the string return you can adjust your code

```
System.getproperty("os.name");
```

Comment: Okey, thanks..in linux run this app good bud in windows i dont can  change write permissions to folder

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.getProperty("os.name")` for obtaining os name, depends on it set path to resource:

```
String resourcePath = null; 
switch (System.getProperty("os.name")) {
            case "Linux":  resourcePath = "/home/romankooo/work/txt/";
                     break;
            case "Windows":  resourcePath = "C:\\PDFMalwareDataAnalyser\\Txt\\";
                     break;
}
```

Comment: Bad approach. Better use everywhere slash ('/') or `File.separator` as @microtone said here in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you'd better get the folder passed in by a system property:

> java -Dfolder=C:\PDFMalwareDataAnalyser\Txt\ myapp

This one you can use like this:

```
public File folderTxt = new File(System.getProperty("folderTxt"));
```

Or pass the folder by a program argument:

> java myapp C:\PDFMalwareDataAnalyser\Txt\

And then use it like this:

```
public File folderTxt = new File(args[1]);
```

But if you're sticking to use constants in your code, you can use it like this:

```
public File folderTxt = new File(String.join(File.separator,"C:","PDFMalwareDataAnalyser","Txt"));
```

Or a newer version of this would be:

```
public File folderTxt = new File(Paths.get("C:","PDFMalwareDataAnalyser","Txt").toString());
```

Or you could also read a property file and store the path in that one. This would work for different OSes, you only have to create the property files before:

```
String propertyFileName = String.format("folderSettings-%s.properties", System.getProperty("os.name").replaceAll(" ","_"));
Properties p = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName))
{
  p.load(is);
  String folderName = p.getProperty("folderName");
  folderTxt = new File(folderName);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // log if error occurs...
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```