# Why am I getting an error about a Windows file path in Java?

Tags: java, windows, file, path

I am getting a "
    `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at parker.MovieLibrary.<init>(MovieLibrary.java:22)
    at parker.SelectorUserInput.main(SelectorUserInput.java:10)`
" error when trying to open a file.

Below is the code of the MovieLibrary constructor that is giving me trouble:

```
    public MovieLibrary() {

        String FILENAME = "\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\Desktop\\JavaIndividualAssignment\\FinalMovieList1.txt";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(FILENAME);
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());
        String[] split;
        try {
            File file1 = new File(input.nextLine());
            input = new Scanner(file1);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                //code to add movies to an ArrayList
            }
                //input.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if (input != null){
                input.close();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I tired all of the suggestions listed here: [Java File Path Windows/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663023/java-file-path-windows-linux)
, but none of them worked.I got the same error each time.
I replaced the backslashes with single forward slashes, tried using the Path object, nothing changed the error.

Is this an issue with my file path? I used the same file-opening code on a different computer and it found the file just fine.

Below is the

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a Scanner object of the filename string (\Users etc). Pretty sure you want to create a File object of the string and a Scanner object of that File object.

Comment: Just tried that, it threw a java.io.FileNotFoundException. I think the issue stems from the file path.

Comment: @Hauntech This does not seem to be a valid Windows file path. Try `"C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\Desktop\\JavaIndividualAssignment\\FinalMovieList1.txt"`, something like that.

Comment: I agree with lexicore. I think it is both things. And examining things in an IDE and/or with print statements after each code action would probably help greatly to debug.

Answer (score -1):

```
String FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\Desktop\\JavaIndividualAssignment\\FinalMovieList1.txt";
 Scanner input=null;
    File file = new File(FILENAME);
    String[] split;
    try {

         input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            //code to add movies to an ArrayList
        }
            //input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if (input != null){
            input.close();
        }

}
```

> Try This