# Running Windows-Compatible .jar files on Linux?

Tags: java

Our CE project includes a .jar file which is written for Windows only for some reason. Unfortunately, I do all my coding related projects on Ubuntu and I'm really not willing to install VS on windows and start over on a new environment and lose a lot of efficiency.

The jar file requires some other files to work but the directory formats differ in Linux so I'm getting errors of it not finding the files when I try to open it from Linux.
I've already asked for the source code or a more compatible version but the TA's aren't really cooperative in my case.

Is there any way I could circumvent this problem and fix the incompatible directory formats issue(For example by running through wine)?

Edit: I tried decompiling the jar, but it wasn't fully successful and some of the files came out corrupted.

Comment: So basically the only problem you have is that your application is looking up some files that are not present?

Comment: If it's just a few hard-coded pathnames, and the application is not too huge, you might be able to decompile it ([this site](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) has a list of decompilers), fix the paths, then re-compile.

Comment: The files are present, and the application does run on Windows, but not on Linux,

Comment: If all files are not present in jar, then what is use of creating it?

Comment: If the Jar is for homework (inferred from "TA"), there is _probably_ not too much you can do. They might not be willing to give you the source code, and have limited capacities for re-working it for Linux. Also, if you use a decompiled and patched version of the Jar, you might risk your code not working when they test it against _their original_ Jar. This may not be the answer you want to hear, but it's probably best to just use Windows for this assignment and start a petition to have OS-agnostic assignments in the future.

Comment: It serves as the graphical UI for the project which runs our custom C codes, located in other directories.

Answer (score 1):

Because the original maintainers didn't think that this JAR would be run on other OSes, you're stuck placating their arbitrary requirement.  You're going to want to use a VM (Wine isn't an emulator and you're going to run into *significant* pain using it and Java to run a JAR) to set this up and execute their JAR.

Once you get a hold of the source, you can [build a new JAR which *asks* the OS which file separator to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663023/java-file-path-windows-linux) instead of allowing the code to *assume* Windows.  Or use [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Comment: I already have Windows in dual boot, however it would take me some time to get adapted to it as I've never done any "coding" related stuff in it. I thought maybe there's an easier way but seems not. Thanks for the answer though